# I need to check if the mathematical calculation labelled as "difference" is giving negative value , if negative then what to do make it positive?

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
SELECT a.name ,  b.name , **(a.marks - b.marks ) AS "difference"**

FROM a , b

WHERE  a.marks - b.marks < 1  AND a.marks - b.marks > -1 AND  a.marks2 - b.marks2 < 1  AND a.marks2 - b.marks2 > -1

ORDER BY `difference` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ABS() that Return the absolute value

From MySql manual:

> ABS(X)
>
> Returns the absolute value of X.
>
> mysql> SELECT ABS(2);
>
> ```
>     -> 2
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT ABS(-32);
>
> ```
>     -> 32
> ```

So:

```
SELECT ABS(-5) + ABS(5)

Return -> 10

SELECT ABS(5-15)

Return -> 10
```

ABS() can also be used on variables:

```
SET @Var :=-5;
SELECT ABS(@Var) + ABS(5)

Return -> 10
```

Comment: okay so that would return me the difference in positive , even if it comes negative ??

Comment: @OmkarDixit It returns the absolute value. See edit in the answer.

Comment: Okay much thanks just one last question , the ABS command  , can it be used with a varialble , because you have used that with a value  ,

Comment: @OmkarDixit I added an example with a variable.

Comment: @OmkarDixit I'm happy to have helped you, but why didn't you accept  the answer?

Comment: sorry my bad , there you go  :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, You could try if() function like mentioned below:

```
Select a.name, b.name, if((a.marks - b.marks) < 0,((a.marks-b.marks)*(-1),  (a.marks-b.marks)) as difference
from a , b ....
```

Comment: actually i am working on phpmtyadmin, i think the if command doesnt work on phpmyadmin , or maybe its not just working for me ,